# How to help a friend determine if they are happy or just settling in a long term relationship?

Tags: relationships, conflict-aversion, acceptable-behavior, estranged-relations, breakups

Through my years until recently I have had friends or just known people who have been in relationships that they generally considered long term and committed, but were open (at least to me) about the fact that they are not really sure about their partner/relationship but are happy with it for now. To be clear, these are all defacto-relationships.

As a friend and having been happily married and have kids, I always want to give them advice on this but never have because I don't know if there is actually any need, or if in fact, I am just applying my own standards to their situation. When I was in high school I didn't think twice about these types of relationships since we were young inexperienced and generally not committed, but now as adults (20-30 yrs old) I find it really hard to wrap my head around the reasoning.

For example, these red flags spring up for me:

1. If they are dating and have only spent a shorter period (eg. < 6 mths) of time with this person I totally get they wouldn't be committed and might not have worked everything out about each other. But why would they still be with this person after eg. 12 months if they are still not really sure about them? I don't get why they wouldn't simply break up with this person and either stay single or find someone better? What is it exactly that they are waiting for in order to make the relationship happier and more fulfilling, or do some people just accept and settle because nothing better comes up? I have asked this before but never really got an answer, so I feel understanding this would allow me to be more helpful to my friends.
2. Is it actually considered healthy to stay in a relationship where the friend (one of the partners) is not completely happy and not feeling fulfilled, or is it better for them to break up? I'm not sure if this is accurate, but from my perspective, I worry about my friends that they will end up settling for this person and then get married and have kids thinking this will fill/fix any relationship deficiencies, which is a huge misconception in my mind, and more likely to lead them to be miserable and/or divorce. I personally feel it is wrong to use marriage or having kids to try to save/improve relationships, but happy to hear from others.

**So the goal here is how do I interact with these friends and provide advice that will help them to (help themselves and) better understand the difference between settling and being happy with someone, and being single and happy vs in an unfulfilling relationship (or series of these)?**

I do understand that breakups are horrible (been through them myself), even for the person breaking things off, but in my experience, I've always thought it is better to do this the earliest you realise it before letting things drift too long into a grey area. In my mind, you are doing both parties a favor, even if a painful one. But I am maybe overlooking something so happy to hear other people's answers on this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the reasons why people stick together (and whether this is harmful) is more a question of psychology. It's not really an Interpersonal Skill, which would be a behavior people use to interact well with others and achieve certain goals.

Comment: Even after edits I still have problems understanding your primary goal here. If I properly understood, you prefer ending unhappy relationships as soon as they're labeled as such, and you'd like to communicate that to the person. But what are your inputs? Would this be based on ***your*** gut feelings about the relationship? How do you decide that you should tell the other person?

Comment: My advice would be to just empathize with them.  They're probably looking for that first anyway, not to be given advice.  They want to feel felt.  Good luck!

Comment: If you worry about friends settling, that's neighborly. If you consider governing their lives based on your own ideals, that is bound to look neurotic for the worry and controlling for the advice. Just saying.

Comment: My advice would be to mind your own business.